# Trouble accessing class field values inside a JobIntentService

Tags: java, android, jobintentservice

I'm trying to use the `JobIntentService` on Android and I'm having trouble accessing the class fields inside the `onHandleWork` method. My `discoverable` field always seems to be null inside the `onHandleWork` method.

Here is my JobIntentService class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import com.orhanobut.logger.AndroidLogAdapter;
import com.orhanobut.logger.Logger;
import io.hypertrack.smart_scheduler.Job;
import io.hypertrack.smart_scheduler.SmartScheduler;

public class NetworkCheckService extends JobIntentService {
  private static final int jobId = 1;

  private Settings settings;
  private NetworkInformation networkInfo;
  private Networks networks;
  private Discoverable discoverable;

  {
    Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());
  }

  // Needs an empty constructor for some reason.
  public NetworkCheckService() {
  }

  public NetworkCheckService(Context context) {
    this.settings = new Settings(context);
    this.networkInfo = new NetworkInformation(context);
    this.networks = new Networks(context, networkInfo);
    this.discoverable = new Discoverable(settings, networks);
  }

  private Discoverable getDiscoverable() {
    return discoverable;
  }

  static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    enqueueWork(context, NetworkCheckService.class, jobId, work);
  }

  public void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    Logger.d(discoverable); // discoverable is null
    Discoverable foo = getDiscoverable(); // foo is null
  }

}
```

My main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NetworkCheckService networkCheckService = new NetworkCheckService(this);
    networkCheckService.enqueueWork(this, new Intent());
  }

}
```

Comment: What Discoverable class is  doing ? i think `discoverable = new Discoverable(settings, networks)` should be in `onHandleWork` if doing any long job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We should not create any constructor in service class**. It does by the android system. This is the reason your member variables becoming `null`. Better to initialize them inside **onHandleWork** method.